Specify Elasticsearch Ingest Pipeline in Spring Data Elasticsearch
I am using the Elasticsearch's 8.x Java API client for indexing documents to Elasticsearch. While indexing, I'm specifying an ingest pipeline to be executed during data ingestion.
public Mono<IndexResponse> addContent(RequestDoc requestDoc) {
        IndexRequest<ContentTransformedModel> indexRequest = IndexRequest.of(request -> request
                .index("test-index")
                .document(requestDoc)
                .pipeline("test-ingest-pipeline"));
        return reactiveElasticsearchClient.index(indexRequest)
                .onErrorResume(IOException.class,
                        e -> Mono.error(new ElasticsearchPublishException(ES_INDEX_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e)));
    }

I want to move this implementation to Spring data elasticsearch. Is it possible to configure ingest pipelines for indexing documents in Spring data elasticsearch?

Rather than considering about ingest pipeline you can use default.ingest_pipeline in index settings and it will affect each new indexing request. After put this settings, you just need to push the data.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#set-default-pipeline

Just to update, I went ahead with this approach.

Did it work? if so I will share it as an answer.

Yes it did work. Thanks.

Nice to hear that. Shared as an answer

Rather than considering about ingest pipeline you can use default.ingest_pipeline in index settings and it will affect each new indexing request. After put this settings, you just need to push the data. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#set-default-pipeline
PUT your_index_name/_settings
{
  "index.default_pipeline": "your_ingest_pipeline_name"
}


I am not so sure but you can probably do it using the ElasticsearchRestTemplate, I believe that it should work, you can find it here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.html
if it didn't work check the ElasticsearchOperations:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchOperations.html
but if you arrived at a dead end maybe this is the only way to do it:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-ingest-put-pipeline.html
